# Android 5.0 isn't included in SDK Platforms

Tags: android, sdk

My smartphone is running android 5.0 and I want to run app on it. But, Android 5.0 is left out SDK platforms(in SDK Manager).

[image]

In standalone manager:

[image]

Screenshot of the error while trying to run:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no Android SDK for 5.0 separate from the Android SDK for Android 5.0.1. You already have the proper SDK installed, based on your screenshots.

Comment: But Android Studio says that my device is incompatible. I tried reboot, adb kill-server etc.

Comment: @GùrìCôppérfîéld: "But Android Studio says that my device is incompatible" -- that has nothing to do with the SDK Manager. As Akshat suggests, edit your question and post a screenshot of the error that you are seeing. However, it needs to be a wider screenshot than what you originally posted, so that you and we can read the contents of all columns, particularly the "Compatible" column.

Answer (score 0):

If you observe carefully that Android Lollipop(5.0) is actually there as android 5.0.1 at api level 21. Actually Lollipop's version name is 5.0.1 so it made you confused.

Comment: But Android Studio says that my device is incompatible. I tried reboot, adb kill-server etc.

Comment: did you just enabled the debugging mode in your device.

Comment: Yes. USB Debugging is enabled

Comment: I got it!! Your device is offline this may be due to you have low memory in device or the data cable you are using does not support your device's debugging mode so try changing either of them.